# MEF: [Import] Null Reference

Tags: c#, .net, mef, caliburn.micro

I'm using Caliburn.Micro with MEF in one of my projects. I can get imports in the root viewmodel. But if I want to get imports into some other classes, it will not work. For example:

```
[Export]
public class A
{
    [Import]
    static ILogger logger;

    public static void SomeMethod()
    {
        logger.Log("foobar");
    }
}
```

And...

```
[Export(typeof(ILogger))]
public class FileLogger : ILogger
{
    public void Log()
    {
        //some implementations
    }
}
```

When I run the application, logger is never set or just equals to null.

Weirdly, if I add an import into the root viewmodel as follows and set a breakpoint there, it works somehow:

```
[Import]
public ILogger logger {get; set;}
```

However, when I press F5 to continue, logger turns out to be null when it comes to the class A. I'm wondering why the value of logger is set to null and in which place.

Comment: Do you create the object yourself or do you call one of the CompositionContainer.GetExport methods?

Comment: @PanosRontogiannis Actually I created it myself.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the `CompositionContainer` to compose or satisfy the imports of the object.

```
A a = new A();
compositionContainer.ComposeParts(a);
```

Otherwise you can use one of the `CompositionContainer.GetExportXXXX` methods. This way MEF will create and compose the object for you.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Unfortunately, it's still not working. Seems MEF just cannot resolve the imports.

Comment: @IsilmëOrphousV Are you using the same CompositionContainer that is used to compose the root viewmodel?

Comment: Yes. I'm doing it in AppBootstrapper so it's definitely the same container.